# Why is libusb 1.0.9 still a very popular download on SourceForge?

Tags: libusb, libusb-1.0

So, wanting to access a USB device from python on Windows, I've spent the morning searching the web and it seems that the most popular, comprehensive and up to date (as of late 2014) combo is [PyUSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyUSB) (1.0.0-beta-2) on top of libusb-1.0 (1.0.19). In particular it took me a while to figure out the current status quo regarding all the politicking, forks, re-combinations and domain name changes that the libusb-1.0 project has undergone over the last couple of years.

So, AFAIK the current official/definitive libusb-1.0 project is hosted at

https://github.com/libusb

has download tarballs at

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb

and maintains a project page at

http://libusb.info/

Given all the ructions, looking at the [SourceForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge) download page I was a bit suspicious to note that while 1.0.19 is the most recent release, 1.0.9 from a couple of years back is still the more popular download. Why?

Comment: If I Google "libUSB", the top result is LibUSB.org, and on there in a prominent place on the front page it says "Download the latest release tarball" with a link to the Sourceforge 1.0.9 download. If I wasn't looking around because of this question, I'd never notice anything different. But looking at the SourceForge download history  for each file, over a long date range, I was expecting 1.0.9 popularity to decrease over time, and 1.0.19 popularity to keep climbing - and that's not happening, is it? I wonder what popular project is hard linking to it?

Comment: For anyone who's unaware of the history, AFAIK libusb.org is the obsolete project homepage, superseded in Jan 14 by libusb.info (as described in [link](http://libusbx.1081486.n5.nabble.com/Libusbx-devel-Announcing-libusb-1-0-18-as-well-as-libusbx-1-0-18-FINAL-td2375.html))

Comment: Looks to me like the owner of the libusb.org domain ended up on the loosing side of the above mentioned ructions and has thrown a sulk, and now despite no longer being actively involved in the project is refusing to update the site with a clarifying notice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy with TessellatingHeckler'e explanation.  The zombie web site libusb.org that links to the old 1.0.9 version of the library on SourceForge has the highest Google page rank and is the first thing people find when searching for details on the project